# What does a browser plug-in enable that can't be done natively in WebKit on the iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, plugins, uiwebview

The [google earth API](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/) looks awesome.  Unfortunately you can't use it on the iPhone/iPad, because the UIWebView does not allow plug-in's.

The functionality as rendered in maps.google.com - earth view is amazing.  What is the technical reason for using a plug-in vs doing something with just AJAX/native?  Is it a technical hurdle, or a business thing?